# Checkbox is not working and it is always unchecked

Tags: jquery

I use  `$('#checkbox_all').attr('checked', false);` to uncheck  `$('#checkbox_all')` when i click for one of the others checkboxes. It works fine but when I click `$('#checkbox_all')` it is not going to be checked.

**So `$('#checkbox_all')` is somehow doesn't work properly it is always unchecked.**

What do I am missing? How to fix it?

Thank you!

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#checkbox_all').attr('checked', true);

        $('input[id^="checkbox_"]').click(function () {
            $('#checkbox_all').attr('checked', false);
        });

        $('#checkbox_all').click(function () {
            alert("!!!");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting checkbox_all to false when any checkbox is clicked even if it is checkbox_all. Also if you are using jQuery 1.7, you should be using [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#checkbox_all').prop('checked', true);

    $('input[id^="checkbox_"][id!=checkbox_all]').click(function () {
        $('#checkbox_all').prop('checked', false);
    });

    $('#checkbox_all').click(function () {
        alert("!!!");
    });
});
```

Comment: The not statement can be consolidated into the selector, like this: `input[id^="checkbox_"][id!=checkbox_all]`

Comment: @Austin Another reason why I love stackoverflow, I learn stuff even when I am helping others out.

Answer (score 2):

Use `prop` instead of `attr`:

```
$('#checkbox_all').prop('checked', true);
```

`prop` deals with properties of the DOM, while attributes deals with attributes and their values. To use attr, which would change the attributes instead of the DOM's `checked` variable, you would do this:

```
$('#checkbox_all').attr('checked', "checked");
```

You can then find all checked checkboxes using jQuery's `.is( condition )`, like so:

```
$('#someCheckBox').is(":checked"); // returns true false
```

OR:

```
$('#someCheckBox').prop("checked"); // returns true false
```

Additionally, on click, you are changing the properties of `#checkbox_all`, wouldn't you want to change the properties of all other checkboxes? Like so:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]")
```

Answer (score 2):

`#checkbox_all` is included in the `$('input[id^="checkbox_"]')` selector, so it's being told to uncheck onclick.